# Set of square matrices = symmetric matrices + antisymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $R^{n×n}$ denote the set of $n×n$ real matrices. Let $S ⊂ R
^{n×n}$ denote the subspace of $n×n$ symmetric
matrices and $A ⊂ R^{n×n}$ denote the subspace of $n × n$ antisymmetric matrices. Show that $R^{n×n} = S + A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Given $M\in\textbf{M}_{n}$, we have

\begin{align*}
M = \frac{M + M^{T}}{2} + \frac{M - M^{T}}{2}
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

Notice that $\displaystyle \frac{M + M^{T}}{2}\in S$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{M + M^{T}}{2}\right]^{T} = \frac{M^{T} + (M^{T})^{T}}{2} = \frac{M^{T} + M}{2} = \frac{M + M^{T}}{2}
\end{align*}

Analogously, observe that $\displaystyle\frac{M - M^{T}}{2}\in A$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{M - M^{T}}{2}\right]^{T} = \frac{M^{T} - (M^{T})^{T}}{2} = \frac{M^{T} - M}{2} = -\left[\frac{M - M^{T}}{2}\right]
\end{align*}

Hence the claim has been proved.

Comment: What? do i need to show they are basis? I was thinking to use the property that $X^T = X $ (symmetric), and that $X^T = -X $ (antisymmetric)

Comment: I will edit my answer in order to provide its complete solution.

Comment: Do you know how does this use the symmetric and antisymmetric property here?

Comment: The first relation shows that $X = X^{T}$ and the second relation shows that $X^{T} = -X$.